# Pass Value to the Same Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `request.aspx` page which displays some fields. I have a copy button which actually copies values for the page into a new `request.aspx` page.so the user can submit without enter all the info again.

This involves, passing a flag to `request.aspx` which decides, whether its a new request or loading an existing one. Now I am wondering what are the better ways to pass this flag to the same page.

Can we use QueryStringor Session or ViewState(since its the same page) or a hidden field that stores the request ID so the copy page can pull up info based on request ID.
I am not sure which is the preferred and best way to do this.

Comment: QueryString is normally the simplest. It has some draw backs but also benefits in that it can be read by javascript. Lot of factors to consider. Session has some overhead. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2072a9/state-management-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: So you're using the copy button to populate form fields? You can probably do this on the client side if you know the key values you're going to need data for on page load.

Comment: The key values of the fields are coming from database based on the request I'd .we are copying onto the same form as well..so can you give in some more detail..if possible a sample snippet

Answer (score 0):

Query String is pass parameter from one page to another.

Session is to store value in server memory for each of the user access so each session value will be unique for each PC

ViewState is to store information in the hidden field of the page, so when you close the browser then information will loss.

My suggestion for you is query string, thank you.